# Statistical error and error propagation

Tags: statistical-significance, error-propagation

I have a quantity defined as:
$P_{frac} = \frac{F_{max}-F_{min}}{F_{max}+F_{min}}$

I also have the value for $F_{max}$, $F_{min}$, and their statistical errors.

How can I calculate the error for $P_{frac}$?

Comment: What, precisely, do you mean by "their statistical errors"? Are $F_{max}$ and $F_{min}$ dependent?

Comment: They are results from a measurement, and then they also are reported with their error. They are not dependent.

Comment: *They are not dependent.* -- out of curiosity, how do you know this?

Comment: They are the maximum and the minimum value of a series of data.

Comment: In which case they're very likely not independent (though if the samples are large, it may be a reasonable approximation).

Comment: Statistical error means the random error (I am sorry, I was always used to call it that way). About the independence of the values, I thought they can be defined independent when they are not function of each other... In this case they are the max and min flux of a pulse profile of a star. Does this mean they are dependent? Thanks for the effort anyway.

Comment: What do you mean by "the random error"? Random error as usually understood is generally an unobservable quantity. On dependence: maxima and minima are generally (weakly) dependent. For example, imagine that *a priori*, there's some very small chance that $F_{max}<m$ for some small $m$. If I know the minimum, $F_{min}=m$, the probability drops from "small" to "zero". That's dependence.

Comment: Hi Glen. I don't know how else to define my quantities. They told me "random error" and this is what I said. I don't even know a possible answer to your question. I guess the error is about the square root of the value. About the dependence, I could not imagine this definition of dependence, but according to what you say, then those quantities are dependent, aren't they?

Comment: Do you the mean standard deviation of the distribution of $P_{max}$? Coefficient of variation? Variance? Mean absolute deviation?  ...

Comment: $P_{max}$ does not exists :) perhaps you meant $P_{frac}$. However, the statistical error is $e_i = X_i - \mu$, where $X_i$ is a value of the normal distribution and $\mu$ its mean.
"A statistical error (or disturbance) is the amount by which an observation differs from its expected value, the latter being based on the whole population from which the statistical unit was chosen randomly". Hope now we are defining the problem a little bit more precisely.

Comment: Yes, I did, that was a typo. What are you quoting? And how do I calculate the quantity you just defined? It's unobservable! We can at most estimate a typical size for it, which takes us back to the questions in my previous comment.

Comment: Quoting from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Errors_and_residuals_in_statistics#Introduction). What do you mean by unobservable? We have a population of measured photons...

Comment: You don't know $\mu$ (if you did, what would you need measurements for?). If you don't know $\mu$, how do you compute $X_i-\mu$?

Comment: I guess, the sample mean is taken as a good estimator of the population mean (from the same source linked above).

Comment: Then can't you simply compute those $e_i$ values for your $P_{frac}$ numbers? Or... consider that perhaps you really want something else, like a standard deviation, or a mean absolute deviation, or a variance,  or ....

Comment: The original question was "HOW to get the error for $P_{frac}$?". As you can see, I am not so expert...

Comment: Now that you've defined what it is - as a purely sample-based quantity, I just told you how to do it. Let $X_i=P_{\text{frac}\,i}$ and apply your formula with $\mu$ replaced by $\bar x$. Every step is laid out there. But I still warn you that what you say you want may not be what you want.

Comment: I thought I had to propagate the error, but it seems not the case. What do you mean by that? What error do you suggest to calculate (or what else)?

Comment: Your expectation that you'd do error propagation would suggest something along the lines of one of the measures I mentioned (or something similar), rather than the 'statistical error' thing. For example, it would be common to look at some approximate formula for the standard error of an estimator (the standard deviation of its distribution). But I don't know that that's what you need. I can't define your problem for you.

Comment: So, you are suggesting not to propagate, but to use the standard deviation?

Comment: No, that wasn't what I was saying.

Comment: What about calculating the standard deviation for $P_{frac}$ and then use the equation (9) [here](http://chemwiki.ucdavis.edu/Analytical_Chemistry/Quantifying_Nature/Significant_Digits/Propagation_of_Error) ?

Comment: If doing a propagation of error calculation, you'd presumably use the standard deviations (or some such measure, see many of my comments) of $F_{max}$ and $F_{min}$ to compute one for $P_{frac}$. That's the basis of the answer I offered. But it would require you to say you're after some particular measure (such as standard deviation) ... which I have been asking about from the beginning.

Comment: Can't really follow you man, and unfortunately we can't move in the chat because of my lack of reputation.

Comment: I can't chat right now anyway, have to go. But I may be back in an hour or so, in which case I'll see what I can do for you, if you're still around.

Answer (score 1):

If you can work it out for $R=\frac{F_{max}}{F_{min}}$, and you can work it out for a reciprocal (multiplicative inverse), then rewrite:

$$P_{frac}=\frac{1}{1+\frac{2}{R-1}}$$

Which involves only shifts, inverses and a scalar multiplication.

Comment: Thanks Glen, but... what about then?

Comment: I don't think I should say more because at present: (i) my very first question in comments remains unanswered; and (ii) you've made some statements that don't seem consistent with each other (and which I don't presently have enough information to choose between). So I don't know for certain what I am supposed to be calculating nor the circumstances under which I am doing it. If you clarify your question sufficiently, I might be able to say more.

Answer (score 0):

addition and subtraction -> add absolute errors

multiplication and division -> add relative errors

so, $\delta_{frac}=\frac{\Delta_{max}+\Delta_{min}}{F_{max}-F_{min}}+\frac{\Delta_{max}+\Delta_{min}}{F_{max}+F_{min}}=(\Delta_{max}+\Delta_{min})\frac{2F_{max}}{F_{max}^2-F_{min}^2}$

absolute error $\Delta_{frac}=(\Delta_{max}+\Delta_{min})\frac{2F_{max}}{(F_{max}+F_{min})^2}$

Comment: In light of the comments to the question, which point out (among other things) the dependence of the variables and imply strongly asymmetric distributions for them, this approach seems unsuitable.

Comment: it was described as a measurement error initially, i wasn't following the comments. i think "my" formula will give a very good approximation in any case