# how do normality check in ks test assess for equivalence or difference in data sets?

Tags: normality-assumption, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

I have a series of data of photon counts versus time. These data are periodic, then I can fold them and obtain an average profile of the data. Nonetheless, some variations appear sometime in the single profiles. To check if the average profile and the single ones are statistically different, they suggested me to use the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test. I am new to this, but it seems very fascinating!

However, the suggested procedure is based not directly on the two data set (the averaged one and the singles ones), but on the residuals. Basically, I should subtract the single profiles to the averaged one, and check if the residuals are normally distributed.

What I do NOT understand is: how could the normality test on the residuals assess the equivalence or the difference of the two data sets?

Comment: I don't think this is an appropriate way to test what it sounds like you're interested in - for a couple of reasons. Rather than ask how to implement some solution to the problem, why not ask the assembled experts about your underlying problem? Are you looking to check whether the within-period profiles are changing over time?

Comment: `I don't think this is an appropriate way to test what it sounds like you're interested in - for a couple of reasons` What are these reasons?
`Rather than ask how to implement some solution to the problem, why not ask the assembled experts about your underlying problem?` Sorry, I can't understand what you are asking.
`Are you looking to check whether the within-period profiles are changing over time?` Not exactly, I want to check if there are systematic variations in the profiles, even if these variations are smoothed out in the averaged profile.

Comment: Let me start with the second item. What I mean to say is the approach suggested to you won't be useful as-is. Yet you have somewhere up in the hundreds of actual expert statisticians who might potentially give substantially better answers, so why not begin at the beginning?

Comment: third item: what does 'systematic variations' mean in a way that is different from what I asked about? This is likely to be the crux of your statistical issue. What kinds of variations? Before you saw the data, what were you expecting?

Comment: First item: (i) the KS is a very low power test of normality. (ii) you already **know** don't have normality, you have *COUNT* data, which besides being discrete and non-negative, won't have constant variation as the mean changes. Why test what you know, *a priori*, to be certainly false?  (iii) there are much better ways to identify those kind of things  (iv) hypothesis tests are likely not answering the underlying questions you probably want to ask here -- it strikes me as probably the wrong tool for the job

Comment: I really appreciate your dedication, but in this way  thread could last for 1year. This is half answer to your "second item". The other half is that it has been suggested by an astrophysicist, and we all know very well that statistical tool and statistics in general are very different when used in a so specified sector, like astrophysics or physics in general. See this discussion http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/89560/statistical-error-and-error-propagation and how fast it has been resolved in http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/103706/error-propagation-of-statistical-error

Comment: Third item: it is different because you asked for a trend, that is a variation in time, I am looking for defined features that are always present but only sometimes visible. What I expect from the data before to look at them, is a profile very similar to the averaged one.

Comment: First item: I see, I read something about indeed, and it seems the KS test is not the best, but they suggested it, so it was from the KS I started. What would you suggest? I would say the alternative could be: Shapiro, Chi-squared, Anderson-Darling. Of these, I know just the Chi-squared.

Comment: I don't follow your reply on the third item at all. On the first item, see my (ii), (iii) and (iv) above which I believe make it clear that any of those goodness of fit tests is a bad choice here. But if I was picking one in spite of all the reasons not to do it at all, Shapiro-Wilk would be the better choice.

Comment: I didn't mean "they are better", it is just they know what I mean even if I do not give too many specifications (that I maybe I myself do not know). So, what was your choice? If you base your explanation on what is clear that I don't know (based on the question of this topic), then this is called empasse :)

Comment: You ask:`Are you looking to check whether the within-period profiles are changing over time?` No, by changing over time could mean they are, i.e., "growing in intensity", or "changing their configuration slowly towards a different one". I am not looking for this. I am looking for a feature, i.e. an extra-peak, that sometimes appears in the profile, but it is smoothed out in the average one.

Comment: "An extra peak" would be included in what I mean by "changing over time". Unchanging over time would mean "identical in shape from period to period". Anything else isn't unchanging.

Comment: The question then is whether two adjacent periods would expected to be more similar than two periods that are not adjacent, or whether adjacent ones should be no more alike that ones that are far apart.

Comment: On the other hand, ruling out things like growth is very useful.

Comment: I think we might focus on the initial question that is the most important to me: how could the normality test on the residuals assess the equivalence or the difference of the two data sets?

Answer (score 1):

> how could the normality test on the residuals assess the equivalence or the difference of the two data sets?

It's essentially useless at that task (actually I feel my second and fourth comments already conveyed that).

Asking this is like asking to asking me to advise you on the best way to clean windows with a hammer.

A goodness of fit test is pretty much *useless* at the task, because its main functionality is almost orthogonal to the problem - it picks up the distribution of deviations, when what matters more is their typical magnitude, and perhaps direction.

As a thought experiment, consider

a) what happens with two fits, the second of which has every residual exactly 100 times the size of the corresponding residual of the first. A test of normality will give identical p-values, but they're not equally adequate. A normality test is precisely orthogonal to the direction of that aspect of the problem.

b) now instead imagine we have data that has a slightly heavy tailed distribution around its population curve - perhaps logistic errors, say, but you have *exactly* the correct functional form. With enough data, you'll reject normality, but that rejection tells you only that you might want to use something other than least squares to fit the model, it *doesn't* tell you you missed a bump on the curve.

As a result, the p-value for a straight goodness of fit test on the residuals tells you almost nothing about the actual issue of whether one curve matches a particular subset of data.

(By comparison, the discussion about the choice of which goodness of fit test to use is more akin to asking what kind of hammer might be best. If we had needed to hammer a Gaussian nail, the KS was almost entirely the wrong kind of hammer, but here we need some tool that's altogether different in its features and direction of operation.)

Comment: Thanks Glen. I am particularly impressed by your statement:`...it picks up the distribution of deviations, when what matters more is their typical magnitude, and perhaps direction.` What do you mean by this? What is intended in this case for "magnitude" and "direction"? Is this referred to the so-called "outliers"?

Comment: 'direction' is simply direction on the real number line ... i.e. the sign. It's not about outliers, at least not directly; the central issue lies elsewhere. The shape of the distribution of the residuals isn't especially important in telling you about good fit. It's the *size* (and in some cases sign) of the residuals.

Comment: Ok, I think I am starting to grab the point. I was now thinking to change the strategy and use the 2dataset KS test on the model and on the single profiles, avoiding to work through the residuals. Is it worthy to open a new topic about this?

Comment: Probably, since it now seems to be a substantively different question.