# Standard deviation of normalized data

Tags: standard-deviation, error-propagation

I have a data set $y_i$ (where the $y_i$ are photon counts in time period $i$, $i=1,2,\ldots,n$, assumed Poisson), with an estimated standard error $s_i$ ($=\sqrt{y_i}$) for each count.

For some reason, I normalize the data set by the average count rate $\bar y$.

$$\bar y = \frac{\sum y_i}{N}$$

where $y_i$ has $i=1,\ldots,N$

The standard deviation of $\bar y$ is calculated as $\sqrt{\frac{\sum (y_i - \bar y)^2}{N-1}}$

To normalize I simply do: $z_i = \frac{y_i}{\bar y}$

At this point how do I calculate the standard error for the $z_i$?

Is error propagation the right thing? $\text{se}(z_i) = z_i \times \sqrt{\left(\frac{s_i}{y_i}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{\text{se}(\bar y)}{\bar y}\right)^2}$

It seems to me that the error stay of the same order as before, while the count rates increase their value about one magnitude. So I am probably missing something.

So, if I print the ratio of the count rate values divided by their standard deviation, before the normalization, I obtain:

```
[  1.06904497   1.07222193  -0.306786     2.22599555   5.04049535
10.44367859  10.37041246   4.71728177  10.85418506  10.99314159
10.18889392   9.20449287  13.24244513  10.70825227  15.64406957
15.41271307  10.06729494  12.88619079  14.76416192   3.90199486
13.33680974  11.57703491   9.38122633  11.53686373  13.32397254
-0.78308901]
```

And after the normalization (plus error propagation):

```
[  2.27976751e+00   2.29330204e+00   1.88194867e-01   9.79928633e+00
4.80280889e+01   1.74659904e+02   1.72699185e+02   4.23542991e+01
1.85693431e+02   1.89443907e+02   1.67854381e+02   1.41988475e+02
2.50472302e+02   1.81762548e+02   3.14047817e+02   3.08069283e+02
1.64619984e+02   2.40831046e+02   2.91120670e+02   2.94284485e+01
2.53020286e+02   2.05263389e+02   1.46572585e+02   2.04172711e+02
2.52673822e+02   1.69702062e+02   2.48534464e+01   1.65477547e+01
4.12770323e+00   4.47260177e-01   1.22474257e+00]
```

Any suggestion really appreciated.

PS: Sorry if the formulas are not well displayed, I don't know how to set the "formula" environment.

Comment: Greek letters (like $\mu$) are conventionally used in statistics to represent population quantities. We generally denote $\frac{\sum y_i}{N}$ as $\bar y$. Similarly, $\hat y$ has a conventional meaning, and so on through your question. It's very confusing when you're using a bunch of familiar notation, but you're not using it in the conventional way.

Comment: Sorry, I had no idea. If you like please feel free to edit the post.

Comment: Thanks, but I hesitate to start because parts of what you have I don't understand well enough to be sure I would leave it meaning what you want it to mean. If I misunderstand what you mean by $\sigma$, for example, I may damage your question. I am I really not sure I do understand that part correctly.

Comment: Please, tell me what is not clear. I put the definition and the formulas just to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: What is the standard deviation of each value? How is it measured? Is it a known population quantity? Is it a sample quantity? I don't know what I am even dealing with there. If those standard deviations are known, your $\bar y$ is an inefficient estimate of $\mu$, since you're not weighting them for precision.

Comment: In my case the standard deviation is calculated as statistical error (or viceversa). That is dispersion from average. If I understood correctly, it is a sample quantity, in which the sample mean is taken as a good estimator of the population mean. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Errors_and_residuals_in_statistics and discussion here http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/89560/statistical-error-and-error-propagation#comment175416_89560 and here

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean at all, and the long discussion at the linked question was to my mind insufficiently clearly resolved on that point. If you have a single observation, $y_i$ how do you get $\sigma(y_i)$? How was it actually obtained?

Comment: It is binned data: it is photon count rate, that means number of photons per unit of time.

Comment: That's important, but again doesn't seem to respond what I am asking, so say I get a count of 10 over whatever unit of time this is in ... how do you get $\sigma(y_i)$?

Comment: $counts = n_{obs} + \sqrt{n_{obs}}$. Then $count rate = n_{obs}/t \pm \sqrt{n_{obs}/t}$, with $t$ integration time.

Comment: Okay now I really have *no idea* what you're talking about. What could such statements possibly mean?

Comment: I showed how to get $y_i \pm \sigma(y_i)$. I thought this was good!

Comment: $counts= n_{obs}+\sqrt{n_{obs}}$ still makes no sense. The $\pm$ wasn't there in the second thing when I looked before. We may be getting somewhere, but we're not there yet.

Comment: Oh sorry, I meant $counts = n_{obs} \pm \sqrt{n_{obs}}$. I tried to edit it but it was too late. Does it ok now?

Comment: Is it that what you're actually trying to say is that there's a Poisson model for the counts and the estimate of the standard deviation of the count, $y_i$ is $\sqrt{y_i}$?

Comment: Yes, it is. Sorry for not mentioning this important detail earlier.

Comment: Okay, I might be able to try to edit it shortly. After I try it, if you think it's wrong you can just revert the edit.

Comment: Why do you take an average count? Are the time intervals all equal?

Comment: 1) I am following the same procedure of another software tool, which normalize to the average counts; 2) yes the binning is constant.

Comment: I have made some changes to notation, and corrected what I believe was an error. (I think there are still some errors in what you have though.) Please check this is okay. Change it back if need be.

Comment: I think it is ok! Just, you use interchangeably the `stardard error` and the `standard deviation` definitions...

Comment: "Standard error" simply means "the standard deviation of the distribution of". The problem is that the distribution of $\bar y$ has a standard deviation (i.e. the standard error), but if that's what you mean then the formula in your post is wrong. You may instead mean "standard deviation of the individual $y$'s", but if you assume Poisson, why would you do it that way?

Comment: @Glen_b, you are right, that way of propagate the error is probably not the right thing. I think, using the formula in [this paper](http://articles.adsabs.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/nph-iarticle_query?1986ApJ...303..336G&defaultprint=YES&filetype=.pdf) is the best in my case. If you or anyone confirm it, it will be possible to write an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using the standard rules for error propagation, as mentioned on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagation_of_uncertainty#Simplification), for each element $i$, the sum can be split into two parts: $a = y_i$ and $b = \sum y - y_i$. Then, ignoring cross-correlation between the elements of $y$:

$$
f(a,b) = a / (a+b) \\
\sigma^2_f = |\frac{df(a,b)}{d a}|^2 \sigma_a^2 + |\frac{df(a,b)}{d b}|^2 \sigma_b^2 \\
\sigma^2_f = (\frac{1}{a+b} - \frac{a}{(a+b)^2})^2 \sigma_a^2 + (\frac{a}{(a+b)^2})^2 \sigma_b^2
$$